# jQuery Mobile Framework and very large data lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

We are using jQuery mobile for one of our projects and we are hitting a dilemma. One of the pages needs to show a very large list of video games that the user should be able to search by typing the video game name. Please see (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/lists/lists-search.html).

How can we implement an optimal solution that gives user the flexibility of typing in the videogame name and still not have performance issues. Possibly sequential loading etc. Also anyone know of any plugins?

Thanks

Comment: How do you define 'very large'? The way this is worded makes me think it's a problem of interface design as opposed to a problem that can simply be addressed with the right 'plugin'.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading might be an option. jQuery Mobile's built in listview search only searches items currently in the list. That means you're probably going to have to roll your own.

You could consider splitting the functionality as well. Search runs via AJAX, while the user can also scroll through a list which loads additional items as they scroll down the page.